# why position of content in cells depends on other cell

Tags: html, css

```
<section id="main_section">
<section id="wraper">

 <section id="content_left">
  <article class="featured_news">
   <header>
    <img src="fonti.jpg" />
   </header>
   <h3>Lorem Ipsum! Ojczyzno moja ty jak słońce</h3>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum ojczyzno moja ty jesteś jak zdrowie ile trzeba cię cenić ten tylko się dowie kto cię stracił.</p>
  </article>
 </section>

 <section id="content_middle">
  <section class="news_row">
   <article><h3>NEWS 1</h3></article>
   <article><h3>NEWS 2</h3></article>
   <article><h3>NEWS 3</h3></article>
  </section>
 </section>

 <section id="content_right">
  <h3>TEST</h3>
 </section>

</section>
</section>

#main_section {
    display: table;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
}

#wraper {
    display: table-row;
}

#content_left, #content_middle, #content_right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
}
```

My question is why position of contents in middle and right cells depends on height of img in left cell? When I delete img everything is alright.

Comment: Could you provide us a fiddle example, please?

Comment: Here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/SF9LM/1

Comment: as you are using `table:cell` your sections will be treated as such so add `vertical-align:top` to your styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the *vertical* position, you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SF9LM/6/

```
#content_left, #content_middle, #content_right {vertical-align: top;}
```

The reason is that table cells align 'middle' by default. By adding the image, you stretch the height of the first cell and all other cells follow suit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfect. But I wonder if is it the best way to make such layout with html5 and css3?

Comment: Maybe not ideal, but neither are floats. By some philosophies, they're a crutch. I'd try to simply use divs with your widths if possible.

Comment: Please remember to select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you made the wrapper `display: table;` and the content sections `display: table-row;` you could get a similar look by making wrapper `display: block` and the sections `float: left;` which would solve your issue. Table divisions inside the same row will all become the height of the tallest one.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SF9LM/7/), thanks @isherwood.